# View this file in Explorer (while open in notepad++)

Tags: macos, windows-7, notepad++

I have file.txt opened in notepad++.exe

This works with all filetypes (.xlsx .txt .tab .csv .pages .scrivener you get it) on OS X:

- I right click the file name using the app I'm in. (On notepad++ on windows, this would be right clicking on my file.txt file.)
- A menu pops up, showing me the path to that file. For example /dropbox/work/projectA/subfolderB/file.txt
- I choose a certain folder, for example the folder /projectA
- That folder opens up in finder.

I want to do this on windows 7. Extra important to do it in notepad++ with .txt-files, since those are part of my GTD-system.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not at all clear about what you want.

Having installed Notepad++ via the normal installer, you should be able to right-click on a file in Windows Explorer (or File Explorer) and select "Edit with Notepad++". That allows any file to be viewed with Notepad++.

The Notepad++ **Run** menu should contain an entry for **Open containing folder** that opens Windows Explorer at the folder containing the current file. This command shoul dbe in the file `c:\Users\{UserName}\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml`. The shortcuts file on My Windows 7 computer contains the line

```
<Command name="Open containing folder" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="0">explorer $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)</Command>
```

If you need to alter the shortcuts file then do not use Notepad++, use another editor.

Comment: @jacob It is better to explain what you want to do in the question. Putting a link to another site to give the details of your question separates the question from the answer. It also risks the details being deleted in the other website leaving an answer in SO but with no question.

Comment: The link is to *my* screencast, 30 seconds long. No reason for me to delete it.